# Transform multiple format Duration Data to common formatted '%H%M%S' . The %M part of the format (minutes) is inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, time, duration

I have Duration data that is an object with multiple formats, particularly in the minutes part between the colons. Any idea, how I can transform this data. I tried everything with regex imaginable (except for the correct answer :) ), which was the main part where I was struggling with. For example, below is my attempt to zero-pad the minutes column.

```
df['temp'] = df['temp'].replace(':?:', ':0?:', regex=True)
```

Input:

```
    Duration
0   00:0:00
1   00:00:00
2   00:8:00
3   00:08:00
4   00:588:00
5   09:14:00
```

Expected Output Option #1 (Time format):

```
    Duration
0   00:00:00
1   00:00:00
2   00:08:00
3   00:08:00
4   09:48:00
5   09:14:00
```

My end goal is to get the minutes, so another acceptable format would be:

Expected Output Option #2 (Minutes - integer or float):

```
    Minutes
0   0
1   0
2   8
3   8
4   588
5   554
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration)
```

Output:

```
0   00:00:00
1   00:00:00
2   00:08:00
3   00:08:00
4   09:48:00
5   09:14:00
Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or Option 2 - Minutes:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

Output:

```
0      0.0
1      0.0
2      8.0
3      8.0
4    588.0
5    554.0
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I forgot about `pd.to_timedelta()` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can do `split` with `mul`

```
df.Duration.str.split(':',expand=True).astype(int).mul([60,1,1/60]).sum(1)
0      0.0
1      0.0
2      8.0
3      8.0
4    588.0
5    554.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is what I was going to try next after being stuck earlier, but I didn't know you could multiply with a list like that after splitting. Cool! Thank you!